# Inverted ED95 and ED5 in drc package

Tags: r, model

My aim is to determine the distance between site of injection of a treatment and target of this treatment with a 0.95 probability of success.

The outcome variable was a binary variable (Success:1/failure:0)

I used Dixon up and down methodology with six distances tested : 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10 mm.
Here are my data :

column 1 : distances used

column 2 : number of success

column 3 : total number of patients

```
data <- data.frame(1:6,1:6,1:6)
data[,1] <- c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
data[,2] <- c(2, 12, 3, 2, 1, 0)
data[,3] <- c(2, 12, 15, 8, 4, 1)
names(data) <- c("Distance", "Success", "Total")
```

I built a model with DRC package 2.3-96  and R ver 3.1.2 on Windows Vista Os :

```
library(drc)
model <- drm(Success/Total~Distance, weights=Total, 
             data=data, fct=LL.2(), type="binomial")

summary(model)
plot(model, bp=.5, legend=FALSE
     , xlab=paste("Distance"), ylab="Probability of success", lwd=2,
     cex=1.2, cex.axis=1.2, cex.lab=1.2, log = "")
```

All seems to be Ok

but when it come to estimating ED 95 (Effective dose 95 : distance required to have 0.95 probability of success), i think that this ED95 was inverted with ED5 (Effective dose 5 : distance required to have 0.05 probability of success) :

```
ED(model, 95, interval="delta")
ED(model, 5, interval="delta")
```

ED95 : 8.0780    SE: 2.0723  CI 95 % (4.0165 ; 12.139)

ED5 : 1.58440     SE: 0.46413 CI 95 % (0.67472 ; 2.4941)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ED values in `drc` package are by default calculated relative to the the control level. In our case, we are looking for ED values calculated relative to the upper limit.

So we must change the `reference` value from `"control"` (default) to `"upper"` :

```
ED(model, 95, interval="delta", reference = "upper")
```

Many thanks to Christian Ritz